# Errors when compiling: "Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct"

Tags: c#, compiler-errors

What is wrong with this code? This program is meant to copy a file and email it to a email address, but it doesn't.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }

    public void email_send()
   {
    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
    SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
    mail.From = new MailAddress("your mail@gmail.com");
    mail.To.Add("to_mail@gmail.com");
    mail.Subject = "Test Mail - 1";
    mail.Body = "mail with attachment";

    System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment;
    attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment("c:/textfile.txt");
    mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);

    SmtpServer.Port = 587;
    SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("your mail@gmail.com", "your password");
    SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;

    SmtpServer.Send(mail);

}
}
```

This shows the following compiler errors:

1. Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct
2. Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct
3. Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct
4. Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct
5. Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct
6. Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct
7. Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected
   Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct

What can I do about this?

Answer (score 18):

The `email_send()` method is outside of the class declaration. It's still inside the namespace, but you must also place it inside the class. Additionally, at no point is the method ever called. It's dead code.

Move the method inside your class definition and then call the method from inside Form_Load()

Answer (score 4):

Exactly what everyone else is saying, but cut/paste this and you should correct the errors:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public void email_send()
    {
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
        mail.From = new MailAddress("your mail@gmail.com");
        mail.To.Add("to_mail@gmail.com");
        mail.Subject = "Test Mail - 1";
        mail.Body = "mail with attachment";

        System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment;
        attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment("c:/textfile.txt");
        mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);

        SmtpServer.Port = 587;
        SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("your mail@gmail.com", "your password");
        SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;

        SmtpServer.Send(mail);

    }
}
}
```

As you can see, your `email_send` method is now inside the class declaration.

Answer (score 3):

You Method is outside the class for one thing.  Copy it into the form 1 class and it should clear up any intellisense issues

Answer (score 1):

email_send method is not defined within a class.